# Why does TimeSpan.ToString() require escaping separators?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

You can specify a custom format for a `DateTime` object like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");   // 19:55:23
```

But when I try to use the same format for a `TimeSpan` object like this:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

I get the `"Input string was not in a correct format."` exception.

It turns out, the solution is that you need to escape the `':'` characters like in `"HH\\:mm\\:ss"`. Note that there is a double backslash because if you specify only one, it will break the string so you need to escape that one too.

The question is, why .NET Framework developers made it this way? There must be a reason for sure. Why can't we use custom format specifiers without escaping them like we can with a `DateTime` object?

Looking for .NET gurus to shed light on this subject.

Comment: This MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx states `The .NET Framework does not define a grammar for separators in time intervals.`, I'm not entirely sure what the reasoning is though (worth a read anyway).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Other), one of the differences between `DateTime.ToString` and `TimeSpan.ToString` format specifiers is the following: *the custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals*.

In [contrast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `TimeSpan` (see table of format specifiers in docs), `DateTime` format specifiers include predefined symbols for Date separator `/`, and for Time separator `:`. It means that for example for Italian culture semicolon will be recognized as time separator (not the literal) and will be replaced with `.` symbol:

```
    // outputs 09.57.18 instead of 09:57:18 because of Italian culture.
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT")));
```

I think .NET designers made such difference between `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` string formatters intentionally, and it is quite reasonable. This is because historically Date/Time were formatted differently for different cultures. And .NET tried to provide globalization means for that matter along with `DateTime` type. But `TimeSpan` did not get such 'globalization' duties, it is just a type representing period of time, and formatting of it is not tied to any culture specifics (if they are ever existed), but instead formatting of it is constant in different culture settings.

Comment: Sergey, `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT"))` does not output '.' instead of ':'. Has there been a misunderstanding?

Comment: @Anar - for me it works great, in your case it probably means that some Windows settings were overriden. Does other cultures formatters work for you? Try "Ru-ru" for example, it should return dates formatted like 04.01.2014

Comment: I read your answer over and over again until I understood almost all of it :). Please explain this part: "... but instead formatting of it (TimeSpan) is constant in different culture settings." If formatting is constant then why does italian timestamp include `.` instead of a "constant" `:`? What am I not understanding?

Comment: @Anar - This sentence is related to formatting of `TimeSpan`, and this formatting is indeed "constant" (culture-independent). My example for Italian culture was related to `DateTime`, which in opposite is culture-dependent. So there is no contradiction here.

Comment: I think I understand now. The main minconception here is that `DateTime`'s **natural form** is a formatted date/time string whereas `TimeSpan`'s natural form is a number (a `long` variable). Custom formatting for `TimeSpan` is not natural, but rather a kind of bonus. Hence no pre-defined formatting options. Yeah, I think I got it now :)