# Why is DateTime.Now.Ticks not consistent?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a simple console application with the following body:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
```

And these are the outputs of three different runs:

```
635258949900018675
635258949900028676   // +10001
635258949900028676   // +0
635258949900038677   // +10001
635258949900038677   // +0
635258949900038677   // +0
635258949900038677   // +0
635258949900038677   // +0
635258949900038677   // +0
635258949900038677   // +0

635258949937502423
635258949937512424   // +10001
635258949937512424   // +0
635258949937512424   // +0
635258949937512424   // +0
635258949937522425   // +10001
635258949937522425   // +0
635258949937522425   // +0
635258949937522425   // +0
635258949937522425   // +0

635258961813519906
635258961813529907   // +10001
635258961813529907   // +0
635258961813529907   // +0
635258961813529907   // +0
635258961813539908   // +10001
635258961813539908   // +0
635258961813539908   // +0
635258961813539908   // +0
635258961813539908   // +0
```

One might guess it is normal for these values to be different since it takes time between `Console.WriteLine` executions. The interval between the lines is a constant value of 10001, but somehow this value is not added to the previous one at EVERY step. Sometimes it is, sometimes it is not. I am wondering why this happens.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - the interval between two different values always seem to be 10001 ticks as far as I can tell. Are you really just asking why there are different numbers of calls between changes? If so, remember just how much is going on in your machine - and how many things can vary.

Comment: Sorry for that. I mean it is not increasing by 10001 at EVERY step. Sometimes it increases and sometimes it does not.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. You almost always respond to questions related to datetime :). I hoped you would see my another question that I am looking for an answer for a long time. I know you don't have much time but could you please share your opinion on this? Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924278/why-does-timespan-tostring-require-escaping-separators

Comment: The answer you've got there looks good to me, to be honest. That's probably what I'd have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Jon:

> Are you really just asking why there are different numbers of calls
>   between changes? If so, remember just how much is going on in your
>   machine - and how many things can vary.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lippert has an excellent [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx) about this topic. Key quote:

> The purpose of the “wall clock” timer is to produce dates and times
>   for typical real-world uses, like “what time does Doctor Who start?”
>   or “when do we change to daylight savings time?” or “show me the
>   documents I edited last Thursday after lunch.”  These are not
>   operations that require submicrosecond accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Although Datetime updates at intervals(which does not happen every tick) you can use a stopwatch to measure time more accurately like this :

```
var sw = new Stopwatch ();
sw.Start ();
//Run some code
Console.WriteLine (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```