# Format Date and Time Textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, time, format

I have two textboxes, one for date and the other for time. The values entered into these textboxes are then saved to a database. But when I reload the page the date and time have reformatted themselves. The date displays as 10/10/2015 00:00:00 but it should only be the date. And the time displays as 19:00:00, but I don't want the last 00 to be displayed.

```
Lookups.CloseTime p = new Lookups.CloseTime(ID);

if (p != null)
{
    txtDate.Text = p.CloseDate.ToString();
    txtTime.Text = p.CloseTime.ToString();
}
```

For the database:

```
private DateTime? _CloseDate;
private TimeSpan? _CloseTime;
public DateTime? CloseDate
{
    get { return _CloseDate; }
    set { _CloseDate = value; }
}

public TimeSpan? CloseTime
{
    get { return _CloseTime; }
    set { _CloseTime = value; }
}
```

Comment: what type is CloseDate/CloseTime?

Comment: @fubo Close Date is DateTime and CloseTime is TimeSpan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ToShortDateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) or `DateTime.ToString("d")` for the `DateTime` without time and [`TimeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `TimeSpan` without seconds:

```
txtDate.Text = p.CloseDate.ToShortDateString();
txtTime.Text = p.CloseTime.ToString("hh':'mm");
```

If `CloseDate` is a `Nullable<DateTime>` you have to use it's `Value` property:

```
txtDate.Text = p.CloseDate.HasValue ? p.CloseDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "";
```

Same applies to the `TimeSpan?`:

```
txtTime.Text = p.CloseTime.HasValue ? p.CloseTime.Value.ToString("hh':'mm") : "";
```

Comment: I can't use ToShortDateString for CloseDate because it causes this error: ` 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: and using CloseTime.ToString("hh':'mm"); causes this error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: The problem is that you're using a nullable datetime. Use p.CloseDate.Value instead, as the edit suggests.

Comment: @user123456789 itsToString("hh:mm")

Comment: @user123456789: i have edited my answer to show you how to get the `Value` from a nullable object.

Comment: @Nikita: no, that's not valid for `TimeSpan.ToString`. Check it out yourself: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm");`. You have to escape the colon with apostrophes. It would work if it was a `DateTime`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I still get the error  No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments for Time

Comment: @TimSchmelter it shuld be probably ("hh\:mm"), not familiar with what you have suggested, is that something new?

Comment: @Nikita: that's the way you have to [escape timespan format strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924278/why-does-timespan-tostring-require-escaping-separators). You could also use `ToString("hh\\:mm")`(double backslash because the backslash itself needs to be escaped)

Comment: @TimSchmelter ohk, haven't seen that before, my bad !! :P

Answer (score 1):

using `.Date` will give you just the Date Portion with a zero'd time component. It's a built in .NET method and will save any bespoke ToString() operations.

`eg. DateTime.Now.Date`

[MSDN Link to DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)